# Can't connect MariaDB from Docker using Python

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am trying to connect mariadb that runs as a docker-compose service. I have antoher service named "app" and includes a new python file in it just to connect db.

It **successfully connects** to *phpmyadmin* but when I try to connect with python it fails for some reason:

error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb:3306' (-3 Try again)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
        sh -c "python3 services/db_connection.py"
    depends_on:
        - mariadb
  prestashop:
    image: prestashop/prestashop
    networks:
      myprestashop:
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - /srv/Configs/PrestaShop/src:/var/www/html
      - /srv/Configs/PrestaShop/src/modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - /srv/Configs/PrestaShop/src/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /srv/Configs/PrestaShop/src/override:/var/www/html/override
    environment:
      - PS_DEV_MODE=1
      - DB_SERVER=mariadb
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWD=mycustompassword
      - DB_NAME=prestashop
      - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=0

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    networks:
      myprestashop:
    volumes:
      - /srv/Databases/PrestaShop:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mycustompassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=prestashop

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    networks:
      myprestashop:
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
    ports:
      - 1235:80
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=mycustompassword

networks:
  myprestashop:
```

**db_connection.py**

```
import mysql.connector as database

connection = database.connect(
    user='root',
    password='mycustompassword',
    host='mariadb',
    database='prestashop')
    
if connection:
    print ("Connected Successfully")
else:
    print ("Connection Not Established")
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `myprestashop` network to your `app` service. If a service does not have any explicitly defined network it uses a `default` one (it's a name like `myproject_default`). So the reason of the error is that the `app` service is in one network and everything else in another (`myprestashop`).